# kurzschwarzhaarige Frau oder kurz schwarzhaarige Frau

Tags: adjective

Sagen wir

> kurzschwarzhaarige Frau,
>
> kurz schwarzhaarige Frau

oder etwas anders?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Es gibt die Adjektive "kurzhaarig" und "schwarzhaarig", aber keines,
das die Kombination der beiden Eigenschaften ausdrückt.
Notfalls könnte man "kurzhaarige, schwarzhaarige Frau" sagen, aber
das klingt sehr seltsam.
Idiomatisch ist "Frau mit kurzen, schwarzen Haaren".

Comment: You could also use »kurz- und schwarzhaarige Frau«.

Answer (score 3):

Ebenfalls könnte man auch sagen:

> Eine Frau mit schwarzer Kurzhaarfrisur